# Configure Multiple Channel in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to make two channels with hyper ledger fabric. In one channel there will be two organizations and in another channel, there will be another two organizations. In every organization, there will be two peers. So total 8 peers in 4 organizations with two channels.  Until now I have done these:

1. In `crypto-config.yaml` file I have declared one orderer and four organizations. In every organization, I have declared template count: 2 and users count: 1 (can anyone please explain the meaning of template count? Is it a total number of peers?)
2. Then used `cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml` command to generate keys and certificates.
3. In `configtx.yaml` file, I have declared two channels with their organization's name:

**Profiles:**

```
FourOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
                - *Org4
TwoOrgsChannel1:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
TwoOrgsChannel2:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org3  
            - *Org4
```

**Organizations:**

```
- &OrdererOrg
    Name: OrdererOrg
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/acme.com/msp
- &Org1
    Name: Org1MSP

    ID: Org1MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.acme.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.org1.acme.com
          Port: 7051

- &Org2
    Name: Org2MSP

    ID: Org2MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.acme.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.org2.acme.com
          Port: 7051

- &Org3
    Name: Org3MSP

    ID: Org3MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.acme.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.org3.acme.com
          Port: 7051

- &Org4
    Name: Org4MSP

    ID: Org4MSP

    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.acme.com/msp

    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.org4.acme.com
          Port: 7051
```

**Orderer: &OrdererDefaults**

```
OrdererType: solo

Addresses:
    - orderer.acme.com:7050

BatchTimeout: 2s

BatchSize:

    MaxMessageCount: 10

    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

Kafka:
    Brokers:
        - 127.0.0.1:9092

Organizations:
```

**Application: &ApplicationDefaults**

```
Organizations:
```

4. Then I have created genesis block using this command

   `configtxgen -profile FourOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block`

Probably, I need to make two genesis block as there are two channels. In that case, what will be the command instead of above one?

5. I have used following commands to make channel transaction and anchor peer transaction.

   ```
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel1 -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel1.tx -channelID mychannel1
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel2 -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel2.tx -channelID mychannel2    
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel1-outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel1 -asOrg Org1MSP
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel1 -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel1 -asOrg Org2MSP
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel2-outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org3MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel2 -asOrg Org3MSP
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel2-outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org4MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel2 -asOrg Org4MSP
   ```
6. Finally used this command to make up:

   `CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel1 docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up –d`

Whenever I am trying to run:

```
CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel2 docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up –d
```

It is saying already peers are running.

So my questions are:

- How can I create multiple channels for different organizations? I
  did not get any elaborative examples.
- Is it possible to communicate between two channels?
- What if peer0 is subscribed to both channels? Will it be able to
  communicate both channels and transfer data in both channels?

Comment: Can you post the error logs ? , cause I been trying the same and got no such error .

Comment: Hi @jaswanth, thanks for your reply. After some trial and error, I have found my problem. I was using a channel name before the docker-compose command, which is not correct. The correct command is just: docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up –d

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, I have found the problem. Actually, I thought, if I want to make multiple channels then I have to use docker-compose command multiple times, which is not correct. The correct syntax for creating multiple channels are:

> cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
>
> export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
>
> configtxgen -profile FourOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock
>   ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
>
> configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel1 -outputCreateChannelTx
>   ./channel-artifacts/channel1.tx -channelID mychannel1
>
> configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel2 -outputCreateChannelTx
>   ./channel-artifacts/channel2.tx -channelID mychannel2
>
> configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel1 -outputAnchorPeersUpdate
>   ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel1 -asOrg
>   Org1MSP
>
> configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel1 -outputAnchorPeersUpdate
>   ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel1 -asOrg
>   Org2MSP
>
> configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel2 -outputAnchorPeersUpdate
>   ./channel-artifacts/Org3MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel2 -asOrg
>   Org3MSP
>
> configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel2 -outputAnchorPeersUpdate
>   ./channel-artifacts/Org4MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel2 -asOrg
>   Org4MSP
>
> docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d

Answer (score 0):

- How can I create multiple channels for different organizations? I did not get any elaborative examples.

  > I think you need one genesis block to bootstrap the orderer. Rest you need multiple channel config transaction files. (.tx). You can use these channel file to create and join the channel using either an SDK (see https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-create.html or https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer/app) or the peer command using the fabric-cli (I could not find a doc but you can try the following sections : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/scripts/script.sh#L61, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/scripts/script.sh#L92)
- Is it possible to communicate between two channels?

> One word answer no. But you can do it via cross-chaincode calls.

- What if peer0 is subscribed to both channels? Will it be able to communicate both channels and transfer data in both channels?

> Yes it can do that. You can refer to http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/channels.html.
>   Inter-channel data transfer is not possible directly. But you can invoke a chaincode (working on channel A) from another chaincode (working on channel B), provided you have permissions to invoke chaincode on both channels.

Comment: Hi @arnabkaycee, thanks for your clarification. I am curious about another thing. Do you know whether one peer can send data to another peer without any channel? If its no, then all data is encrypted in all transactions, as a channel is using symmetric cryptography for encryption. Isn't it?

Comment: @SwawibeAlam What do you mean by sending data without channel? Peers exchange transactional and chaincode data via gossip.

Comment: Hi @arnabkaycee, by 'sending data without channel' I meant, is it possible to do anything without a channel? Please correct me if I am wrong. The process in HF V1.0 is: at first peers join in a channel. A client sends a proposal to the endorsers. Endorsers give an endorsement and send it to the client in a channel. Client broadcast endorsement to the orderer in a channel. Orderer sends Block to committer in a channel. Everything is happening inside a channel. Now, for example, if I have just one organization. I don’t need a channel. Is it possible to do all these things without channel?

Comment: Hi @arnabkaycee, I have another query. Do you know, what is a default encryption mechanism for a channel data? I think It is a symmetric encryption. But is it AES128/256 or another algorithm? By default, is it enabled or I need to enable it? If I need to enable it then how will I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this profile config

```
FourOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        ConsortiumOne:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
        ConsortiumTwo:
            Organizations:
                - *Org3
                - *Org4
TwoOrgsChannel1:
    Consortium: ConsortiumOne
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
TwoOrgsChannel2:
    Consortium: ConsortiumTwo
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org3
            - *Org4
```

This works for me.

[Setting Hyperlegder Fabric Network Multiple Chaincodes Channels](https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-hyperledger-fabric-network-multiple-chaincodes-channels/), hope this article also can help you.