# Can some one share fabric multi channel example using hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

There is no clear documentation of hyperledger fabric multichannel, can someone from community share example of configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This Stack Overflow thread on creating multi-channel for a Hyperledger Fabric configuration  should help you (mostly in yellow and grey code blocks)  -> [Configure Multiple Channel in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954083/configure-multiple-channel-in-hyperledger-fabric).

Once you have configured your custom runtime Fabric environment for your multi-Org, multi-channel setup, you can then create the requisite Hyperledger Composer config artifacts (eg. such as business network cards, one for a PeerAdmin for runtime install on the two peers in a specific organisation,  and one card for a PeerAdmin to instantiate/start the business network across all the multi-Org peers joined to the specific channel in question) - and thereafter, issue cards for the individual identities that will consume/transact on the business network (on whatever channel the connection profile information is set up to communicate on).  See this Multi-Org tutorial (for two Organisations, but similar principles apply) https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html for guidance.