# can we add multiple channels for each participants and identify in hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

can we add multiple channels for each participants in our business network using hyper ledger fabric and hyper ledger composer.

Please suggest on this question .

Answer (score 0):

In Composer, business networks are deployed to a *single* Fabric channel, and Composer business network *cards* are used to interact with that particular business network (instantiated on a single channel) at any one time.

You can however have multiple channels (ie a Fabric concept) in your blockchain network if your architecture dictates - and instantiate business networks on those different channels - but you would need the correct business network cards (ie with appropriate connection profiles representing the channel desired ; a connection profile is part of the metadata comprising the business network card) to reflect this and are obviously business networks with separate ledgers, on each of those channels.

Comment: can you please provide link or steps for instantiating multiple channels.

Comment: sure - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161972/can-some-one-share-fabric-multi-channel-example-using-hyperledger-composer (for related info). See also the first 3 paragraphs (only) of this comment for more info https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2103#issuecomment-400335080